# 2 models inside an IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I am having a difficult time trying to get my models correctly, is there anyway I can fit 2 models inside an IEnumerable? This is what I have..

```
public class threadreplying
{

    public IEnumerable<profile,Threadpost> IEThreadpost { get; set; }
    public taker orginalthread { get; set; }


}
```

The IEnumerable only takes 1 argument how can I make the IEthreadpost work? I am doing it like this because I am implenting a Join in my sql and require information from both models that are stored in a database. I have also tried to do this

```
 public class ModelMix
{
    public profile profiles { get; set; }
    public Threadpost threadposts { get; set; }
}

public class threadreplying
{

    public IEnumerable<ModelMix> IEThreadpost { get; set; }
    public taker orginalthread { get; set; }


}
```

This works but it does not work inside the view it gives me a null error eventhough I am checking against that

```
@if (Model.IEThreadpost != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost)
    {
        @item.threadposts.post
    }
   }
```

Comment: You are getting the error because the threadposts property is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `@item.threadposts` for null.

```
@if (Model.IEThreadpost != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost)
    {
        @if (item.threadposts != null)
        {
            @item.threadposts.post
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you should recognize ahead of time what the implications of doing that check are, and you should ensure that this isn't an indication of your previous logic, where you actually do your `select`.